Calculate a value in looker studio with different Data Sources
I'm working with Looker Studio, I have 2 different data sources DS 1 having A,B,C fields. And DS2 having D,E fields. I need to calculate a field F such that F=B*E. Please suggest how I can do this.
So far, I have tried adding all the details into one data source that didn't work as DS 1 and 2 have differnet dimensions.
I can't blend as neither has any common fields to do it on.
I tried to create bridge field yet again I don't have a common field so I tried to add a parameter in DS1 such that parameter ID and field ID are same. But no luck.
